# How to get EC2 instance availability zone and id using php in aws?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I don’t know not to get EC2 instance availability zone and instance id details using php in amazon web services. As I don’t know how to fetch data, so I haven’t tried anything. Help me out.

The thing I want:
/info

This is exact what I wanted:
[image]

In that info page I can want to display that Instance details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to display the current instances availability zone and ID (the one its running on), or you want to look up an instance in AWS and check what these meta-datas are?

Comment: I want to display current availability zone and Id of the instance on index.php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current instances values by using the [meta-data api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html), these can be accessed from within your application by using a HTTP request library such as [GuzzleHTTP](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or by using native [cURL commands](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) built into PHP.

To get the instance ID you would need to request from your current server to the following URL.

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

To get the instances current availability zone you would need to request from your current server the following URL

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

Assuming you use GuzzleHTTP it would be as simple as calling the below

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id');
echo "Instance ID: " . $response->getBody();
$response = $client->get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone');
echo "Availability Zone: " . $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to display the availability zone and instance id on an web page called index.php.

Comment: The page should not matter as long as the host is an EC2 it can call these endpoints, if you check out the last of the answer you'll see how to call one of the meta-data endpoints :)

Comment: No problem, have a great day :D